Git does not wait for the external editors to close
I am facing this problem since over a month and could not find a similar issue reported on Internet.
I have various editors configured in Git config. I use Notepad++ as editor (for editing commit messages and interactive rebase), WinMerge as the difftool and Visual Studio as mergetool. Earlier, when issuing commands such as git commit or git difftool, Git would wait for these editors to close. Now, the same commands have stopped waiting. Since the commands exited prematurely, the commit message edited in Notepad++ gets ignored, and the temporary files created for the difftool are deleted before it can diff the revisions.
I have reinstalled and upgraded Git and rebooted computer a couple of times so far. It is possible that the issue is caused when cleaning up a few files/folders on PC but I cannot say for sure as the Git installation was untouched. Can you suggest on where the issue might be? Also, if someone can share a method to debug this issue, that would be great.
For now, I have removed the configuration for editors so Git can open the default Vim editor in the console. Also, I am currently using Git explorer inside Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code for diff-operations, but I would like to switch back to the command line.
In case, it helps, sharing the relevant Git configuration below:
[core]
    editor = notepad++.exe -multiInst -nosession -notabbar -noPlugin
    longPaths = true
[diff]
    tool = winmerge
[difftool]
    prompt = true
[difftool "winmerge"]
    cmd = WinMergeU.exe -e -u \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    keepBackup = false

EDIT: Just opened my old laptop and issued git commit command. That too did not wait for Notepad++ to close, so this might be caused by a recent Windows update. Here's the logging when GIT_TRACE environment variable set to 1.
> git commit
09:38:38.106555 exec-cmd.c:266          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Users/username/scoop/apps/git/2.47.0/mingw64/bin
09:38:38.163388 git.c:479               trace: built-in: git commit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
09:38:38.229461 run-command.c:667       trace: run_command: GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/index 'notepad++.exe -multiInst -nosession -notabbar -noPlugin' C:/myrepo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
09:38:38.231049 run-command.c:928       trace: start_command: C:/Users/username/scoop/apps/git/2.47.0/usr/bin/sh.exe -c 'notepad++.exe -multiInst -nosession -notabbar -noPlugin "$@"' 'notepad++.exe -multiInst -nosession -notabbar -noPlugin' C:/myrepo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.

I have switched to Visual Studio Code which lets the Git wait for the tabs to close. It is not clear why Git used to work properly with Notepad++ and WinMerge earlier. Below are the new Git configurations:
[core]
    editor = \"C:\\Users\\jasanghv\\scoop\\apps\\vscode\\current\\bin\\code\" --disable-extensions --wait
    longPaths = true
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Users\\jasanghv\\scoop\\apps\\vscode\\current\\bin\\code\" --diff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" --wait
    keepBackup = false
[merge]
    tool = vscode
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
    keepTemporaries = false
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Users\\jasanghv\\scoop\\apps\\vscode\\current\\bin\\code\" --merge \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\" --wait
    keepBackup = false
    trustExitCode = true


probably the process that git started is finished, even though the editor is still open... not git's fault. It can't just guess that the file is still open. You need to find an editor that blocks or find a way to get the editor you are using to block until you close the file.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git%20notepad%2b%2b -- odds are that others found and solved the issue before already.

The issue could be due to how git interacts with external editors, especially when they are not blocking the process. Check if the editor configurations have background execution flags that prevent Git from waiting. For Notepad++, try adding -wait to the command in the Git config: editor = notepad++.exe -multiInst -nosession -notabbar -noPlugin -wait.
Additionally, ensure that WinMerge and Visual Studio are configured to block Git until the process is complete.

Notepad++ does not have -wait option. The problem is across all editors. The same Git config used to work before.
